# My slideshows are not working with node in localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

As you can see I have positioned my divs properly  position: relative; for slideshow and  position: absolute; for containers

I have looked at similar questions that others posted and tried to fix the issue. It is still not working. Everything else works except slideshows. Slideshow shows only the last image. Does not change. My side panels work perfectly.

previously I had not added $(document).ready(function ()...  In hopes of fixing issue I tried it but something else seems to be the problem. Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

here are my files

```js
//jshint esversion:6


$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
  setInterval(function(){
    $('#slideshow > div:first').fadeOut(1000).next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
      },  3000);

});


/* Set the width of the sidebar to 250px (show it) */
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "250px";
}

/* Set the width of the sidebar to 0 (hide it) */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
img{
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

}


.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.container img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 20px;
}

.QuoteBox{
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  text-align:center;


}

.authorName{
  color: #e79cc2;
  font-family:'Cinzel', serif;


}

p{
  color: #a6dcef;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
  align-items: center;


}

.slide{
  background-image: url('https://paintingvalley.com/images/dark-abstract-painting-11.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #ff4301;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;


}

.backmost{
  /* background-color: #1f4068; */
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

}

.slide{
  /* background-color: #e1ffc2; */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 25px 25px 50px 0 #111d5e inset, -25px -25px 50px 0 #111d5e inset;

}

#slideshow{
  /* background-color: #ffa931; */
  top: 0;
  left: 37px;
  height: 91.75%;
  width: 94.75%;
  position: relative;

}

#slideshow > div > img{
    position: absolute;
}






/* The sidepanel menu */
.sidepanel {
  height: 250px; /* Specify a height */
  width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #192965; /* Black*/
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidepanel */
}

/* The sidepanel links */
.sidepanel a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidepanel a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidepanel .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

/* Style the button that is used to open the sidepanel */
.openbtn {
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #192965;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #192965;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Name</title>
    <link href="/css/homestyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel&family=El+Messiri&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="backmost">

      <div class="slide">

        <div class="QuoteBox">
          <p>“Vision is the art of seeing things invisible.” <span class="authorName"> ― Jonathan Swift</span></p>

        </div>

        <div id="mySidepanel" class="sidepanel">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Work Experience</a>
          <a href="#">Art</a>
          <a href="#">Football</a>
        </div>
        <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Pawan Panta</button>


        <div id="slideshow">


          <div class="container">
            <img src="/images/IMG_E2670.JPG">

          </div>

          <div class ="container">
            <img src="/images/IMG_E2668.JPG">

          </div>


          <div class="container">
            <img src="/images/IMG_E2665.JPG">

          </div>


        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <script src="myWebJs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="JsFiles/homepageJS.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications in `$(document).ready()` and replaced the images with inline data to visualize the fade in / fade out and the images get replaced now.

Looks like the `fadeOut` function returns immediately and not after the fading is finished. I created a callback function which gets called once `fadeOut`, see https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ which seems to do the trick.

```js
//jshint esversion:6


$(document).ready(function (){
  //$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
  setInterval(function(){
    $('#slideshow > div:first').fadeOut(1000, "linear", function() { $('#slideshow > div:first').appendTo('#slideshow'); });
    $('#slideshow > div:first').next().fadeIn(1000);
      },  3000);

});


/* Set the width of the sidebar to 250px (show it) */
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "250px";
}

/* Set the width of the sidebar to 0 (hide it) */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
img{
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

}


.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.container img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 20px;
}

.QuoteBox{
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  text-align:center;


}

.authorName{
  color: #e79cc2;
  font-family:'Cinzel', serif;


}

p{
  color: #a6dcef;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
  align-items: center;


}

.slide{
  background-image: url('https://paintingvalley.com/images/dark-abstract-painting-11.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #ff4301;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;


}

.backmost{
  /* background-color: #1f4068; */
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

}

.slide{
  /* background-color: #e1ffc2; */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 25px 25px 50px 0 #111d5e inset, -25px -25px 50px 0 #111d5e inset;

}

#slideshow{
  /* background-color: #ffa931; */
  top: 0;
  left: 37px;
  height: 91.75%;
  width: 94.75%;
  position: relative;

}

#slideshow > div > img{
    position: absolute;
}






/* The sidepanel menu */
.sidepanel {
  height: 250px; /* Specify a height */
  width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #192965; /* Black*/
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidepanel */
}

/* The sidepanel links */
.sidepanel a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidepanel a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidepanel .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

/* Style the button that is used to open the sidepanel */
.openbtn {
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #192965;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #192965;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Name</title>
    <link href="/css/homestyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel&family=El+Messiri&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="backmost">

      <div class="slide">

        <div class="QuoteBox">
          <p>“Vision is the art of seeing things invisible.” <span class="authorName"> ― Jonathan Swift</span></p>

        </div>

        <div id="mySidepanel" class="sidepanel">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Work Experience</a>
          <a href="#">Art</a>
          <a href="#">Football</a>
        </div>
        <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Pawan Panta</button>


        <div id="slideshow">


          <div class="container">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">


          </div>

          <div class ="container">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">

          </div>


          <div class="container">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACsAAAAzCAYAAAAO2PE2AAABQmlDQ1BJQ0MgUHJvZmlsZQAAKJFjYGASSCwoyGFhYGDIzSspCnJ3UoiIjFJgf8LAwcDKIM5gzKCTmFxc4BgQ4ANUwgCjUcG3awyMIPqyLsgs5ePLNiyYJnbX/yGf7M4vyS8w1aMArpTU4mQg/QeIk5ILikoYGBgTgGzl8pICELsFyBYpAjoKyJ4BYqdD2GtA7CQI+wBYTUiQM5B9BcgWSM5ITAGynwDZOklI4ulIbKi9IMDh7W5kbqgQQMCppIOS1IoSEO2cX1BZlJmeUaLgCAyhVAXPvGQ9HQUjAyMDBgZQeENUf74BDkdGMQ6EWCIwXAyB/mM8hBDLjmBg2OfLwMDHhxDTbGJg4P/MwHA4tiCxKBHuAMZvLMVpxkYQNvd2BgbWaf//fw5nYGDXZGD4e/3//9/b////u4yBgfkWA8OBbwD1NV/22PjJgQAAAFZlWElmTU0AKgAAAAgAAYdpAAQAAAABAAAAGgAAAAAAA5KGAAcAAAASAAAARKACAAQAAAABAAAAK6ADAAQAAAABAAAAMwAAAABBU0NJSQAAAFNjcmVlbnNob3TSkTaFAAAB1GlUWHRYTUw6Y29tLmFkb2JlLnhtcAAAAAAAPHg6eG1wbWV0YSB4bWxuczp4PSJhZG9iZTpuczptZXRhLyIgeDp4bXB0az0iWE1QIENvcmUgNS40LjAiPgogICA8cmRmOlJERiB4bWxuczpyZGY9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkvMDIvMjItcmRmLXN5bnRheC1ucyMiPgogICAgICA8cmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIHJkZjphYm91dD0iIgogICAgICAgICAgICB4bWxuczpleGlmPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL2V4aWYvMS4wLyI+CiAgICAgICAgIDxleGlmOlBpeGVsWERpbWVuc2lvbj40MzwvZXhpZjpQaXhlbFhEaW1lbnNpb24+CiAgICAgICAgIDxleGlmOlVzZXJDb21tZW50PlNjcmVlbnNob3Q8L2V4aWY6VXNlckNvbW1lbnQ+CiAgICAgICAgIDxleGlmOlBpeGVsWURpbWVuc2lvbj41MTwvZXhpZjpQaXhlbFlEaW1lbnNpb24+CiAgICAgIDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPgogICA8L3JkZjpSREY+CjwveDp4bXBtZXRhPgri4qKfAAAEkklEQVRoBe1YWSh1XxRfZsk8hQgZMpbyQkJeTKUkSUmUpLxJiQdPkichociLDMWLN1LKlCI8IPOUuUTKUIb4/3+77/rOOfuee885996v76u7Smev3153nZ911t5r7W0THBz8TX+ZXFxcUEhICMfKlkP+YsBK1lIfxxpZa2T/j8A/lQb25vxknp6elJ+fTwkJCeTv78/+bGxs6Pr6ms7Pz9nf6ekpLS8v09fXl+pXm4Wsj48PtbS0UG5uLjk4OHAkkpKSRBgId3R00OTkJH1/K69JNqZWsJSUFOrt7SU/Pz8RISXK4eEhlZWV0c3NjcjcIhUMJXFwcFATUbCLioqivr4+srdX9oFNWmCIqLu7uygqOuXh4YHm5+dpaGiIpqam6Pb2VjcleiYnJ1NTU5MIk1M0p0F6ejqNjo5yfk9OTqiqqoqOjo5Ec46OjlReXk719fXk5uYmmkPexsfH09PTE8PNngalpaWiF0LZ3t6moqIijijm3t/fWcrU1tZyOwF2jNjYWJgZFE1p4OTkRDk5OSLHIIPFcn9/L8KlytzcHA0PD0thiouL4zApoIlsYGAggbBQZmdnCXmqRFZXVzmzmJgYDpMCmsgGBARI/dDKygqHyQFvb2/clJ2dHYdJAU1kUZ2kcnV1JYVkdWmRgOHZ2ZmsvW5C2Qans/71XFhYoIaGBhG6trYm0uUURDAzM5Obxi5iTDSRfXx8pLGxMWO+uXlnZ2fq7+9nvYNwEotycXFRCOkdayKr15MB0NfXl0UT+29iYiJn2d7eTs/PzxwuBSxCtqCggLq6uujl5YVcXV1lyyk6r56eHhoZGZHy0qtbhKyXlxfrvtAyGpLW1laWFoZshHOadgOhA1PGzc3NND4+Tt7e3orcWITsx8eHopfDKDU1lSYmJhR1bpobGWNs0D5im0KfiyISHh5OxcXF7KnvtzMzM6wBwpxcI2MxsvoIAcvIyKDu7m7u06Pzys7Opr29PVmyFkkDOaLAUVCqq6tZFya0Q+dVUlIihLjxHycLBmhk0JRLJSwsTAqJdNVbF44gNTU1ZGv7+//EWWp6elrk2JiyubnJmYSGhnKYEFBNNigoiBobG4U+aGNjQzXZ4+NjkQ8oOE0Ykt/hMWQlmLu8vOTyLSIiQmChbKivYOALGRLVZFEice4XioeHB0VHRwsho2N9PcLu7q7B36kmC2/62jkcaZQKKlZlZSVnvrOzw2FCQBPZpaUloQ82Blk0MMYEC7Ozs5MVCqEtvtjW1pYQ4saayOIILk0FnMnQQeH0KidpaWlsIWZlZXEmAwMD7C6MmxAAmisY7rXwAn2C3hT5t7+/z7Y4FxcXdvuCuwF9cnBwQHl5eT8L1yLlFhHGZYcp8vn5ydIHdw46kSOrKQ10TisqKtilnJbrS/hYX1/niOp863uaRBatYFtbG6vp2H+Vyt3dHdXV1VFhYSG7xVH6O805K30BDoO4qIiMjGT5iSfKJ25qcKWJ7Q6LEk+U2tfXV6mLH10uDcxG9udNZhjIkTUpDczAS5ULK1lV4VJhbI2simCpMrVGVlW4VBj/U5H9D0vDidBfhHynAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">


          </div>


        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <script src="myWebJs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="JsFiles/homepageJS.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```